# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to '(bool valorA, bool valorB)' c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, boolean

I'm having a problem, I want to make a **Switch Case** that says who won, who lost or if they drew ( Venceu, Perdeu e Empatou).

I did it first with integer values, with int valueA and valueB, where if someone wins it's worth 1, whoever loses it's 0 and a tie, both are worth 1.

However, it ended up giving the error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to '(int valueA,
> int valueB)'

So I redid using boolean values, 1 = true and 0 = false.

But the error still persists and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
if(Input.GetKey(key1))     // Vence
        {
            animBlue.SetBool("AzulTiro", true);
            valorA = true;
        }
        else if(animRed.GetBool("VermelhoTiro") == true)   // Perde
        {
            animBlue.SetBool("AzulMorte", true);
            valorA = false;
        }
   


        if(Input.GetKey(key2))     // Vence
        {
            animRed.SetBool("VermelhoTiro", true);
            valorB = true;
        }
        else if(animBlue.GetBool("AzulTiro") == true)     // Perde
        {
            animRed.SetBool("VermelhoMorte", true);
            valorB = false;
        }



    switch (valorA, valorB)
    {
        case (valorA == true && valorB == false):
              Debug.Log("Azul Venceu");
              break;
        
        case (valorA == false && valorB == true):
              Debug.Log("Vermelho Venceu");
              break;

        case (valorA == true && valorB == true):
              Debug.Log("Empatou");
              break;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the error is on the Switch but I don't know what it is

Comment: Would it not be better to make a win worth 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3):

wrong syntax, you need

```
  switch (valorA, valorB)
    {
        case (true ,false):
              Debug.Log("Azul Venceu");
              break;
        
        case (false , true):
              Debug.Log("Vermelho Venceu");
              break;

        case (true, true):
              Debug.Log("Empatou");
              break;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be true, true?

Comment: Typo in the last case, should be `true, true`. I didn't know you could do this with switch in C#. Don't know why I would, but at least I learned something new. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's a new feature in c# .Net 6.0 called pattern matching. It's undiscovered territory for me too.

Comment: I can't believe it was such a silly mistake :)
thanks friend, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

How about pattern matching if your C# is modern enough?

```
var msg = (valorA, valorB) switch {
  (true, false) => "Azul Venceu",
  (false, true) => "Vermelho Venceu",
  _ => "Empatou"
};

Debug.Log(msg);
```

I reasoned that a false/false would either not occur, or be a draw too. If it isn't then you can tweak the statement:

```
var msg = (valorA, valorB) switch {
  (true, false) => "Azul Venceu",
  (false, true) => "Vermelho Venceu",
  (false, true) => "Empatou",
  _ => null
};

if(msg != null) Debug...
```

Remember that this a value-providing statement rather than an action-taking one; you'll get complaints from the compiler if it isn't exhaustive (doesn't cover all possible input values) and the easiest way to make it so is to provide the "else" case `_`. Also because it's providing values rather than performing code, you might need to inspect the value if you're making a "do/don't" decision.

You can't use this to run actions that are void (assuming Debug.Log returns void) in the same way you can't put voids in a ternary; the ternary produces values:

```
//no
someBoolean? Debug.Log("yes") : Debug.Log ("no");

//yes
Debug.Log(someBoolean? "yes" : "no");
```

One trick you can pull, however, is to use a switch (or a ternary) to return a lambda that you then execute

```
Action a = (valorA, valorB) switch {
  (true, false) => () => Debug.Log("Azul Venceu"),
  (false, true) => () => Debug.Log("Vermelho Venceu"),
  (true, true) => () => Debug.Log("Empatou")
  _ => () => {}
};

a(); //execute the returned action, which may be the do-nothing action
```

These switches *do* return a value; they each return an Action and later it can be invoked to carry out the logging

It can also be formed and executed in one line, though it starts to get a bit "wtf?":

```
((valorA, valorB) switch {
  (true, false) => (Action)(() => Debug.Log("Azul Venceu")),
  (false, true) => () => Debug.Log("Vermelho Venceu"),
  (true, true) => () => Debug.Log("Empatou")
  _ => () => {}
})();
```

Comment: I think I got the idea, I'm starting now in this area, I still have little knowledge, but thanks anyway

Comment: This is going to log for the `(false, false)` case which doesn't seem to be the OP's intention.

Comment: @juharr I was working on the assumption that false/false is either a draw like true/true, or doesn't occur due to a factor we can't see, and was mainly using it to demonstrate the "else" case, but I have made an edit to address your concern